# Function with variables that are different dataframe sizes

Tags: r

So I´m trying to run the fuction below hoping to get 224 vectors in the output, but only get one and I have no idea why.

```
ee <- 0.95
td <- 480

tt <- c(60,10,14,143,60)
tt <- as.data.frame(tt)

r <- vector()

m <- function(d)
{
    n <- length(tt)
    c <- nrow(d)
    for (j in 1:c)
{
    for (i in 1:n)
{
    r[i] <- tt[i]/(td*ee/d[j,])
}
    return(r)  
}

#where d is a data frame of 224 obs. of 1 variable
```

and the output i´m getting is

```
[[1]]
[1] 1026.3158  171.0526  239.4737 2446.0526 1026.3158
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: you probably need to rbind your result or add a j index to r otherwise it just keeps on adding to r[1], r[2],..r[n] so you only get one vector at the end (the last one)

Comment: my expected output are 224 vectors of length = 5

Comment: @kluu You should not edit code to **fix** it in question. Specially when this is a source of problem.

Comment: A parenthesis was missing, making the code not runnable. I just moved some parentheses here and there to reach the 10 characters edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that your function returns only the last `r` vector that is computed, due to where `return` is placed within your loop. 
One way to do this is to store the results in a list:

```
r <- vector()

m_bis <- function(d) {

  res <- list() # store all the vectors here

  n <- length(tt)
  c <- nrow(d)

  for (j in 1:c) {
    for (i in 1:n) {
      r[i] <- tt[i] / (td * ee / d[j,])
    }
    res[j] <- r
  }  
  return(res)
}
```

That should yield something like this:

```
m_bis(as.data.frame(mtcars$mpg))
> [[1]]
  [1] 2.7631579 0.4605263 0.6447368 6.5855263 2.7631579
  ...
  [[32]]
  [1] 2.8157895 0.4692982 0.6570175 6.7109649 2.8157895
```

Comment: See my comment under the question, please avoid turning a broken code into a correct one in questions please.

Comment: I don't understand, I didn't fix the code. I just changed the formatting to make it easier to read.

Comment: There's an extra closing bracket in your edit, which of course make the code working where the actual one won't define properly the function, this may be just a bad copy paste, or there's maybe something else in the function the op did forget, you can't guess and as such you shouldn't be fixing a code which is incomplete.

Comment: I don't see why it is wrong **here** since the nature of the problem has been clearly established. I just thought that making the mentioned problem reproducible was more important.

Comment: that just not your job, that's the question author job, you may comment to tell it to them but you should not put words in their mouth by changing what their question is.Fixing the spacing only would be ok, making the code runnable is not. Please see [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/3627607)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing to this page. One can read in the *Do* section of the **Editing Code in Questions** part: Fix Syntax (non-closed brackets, missing semi-colons, etc.), **unless they are relevant to the question**. Again in that case, I don't think that was relevant to the question.

Comment: I think it is, an answer here should point out the bad formatting which often leads to this kind of misplaced statements, the original formatting is also part of OP problem.

Comment: Well, that is up to one's personal appreciation.

Comment: Votes on comment seems to show I'm not the only one on this line.

Comment: Yet you still haven't been able to explain how **in this case** the missing bracket is relevant to the question. The output given by the author clearly indicates that the function is *at least* runnable. I only added the last bracket that is a necessary condition to have a runnable function. How bad can it be to change `f = function(x) {return(x)` to `f = function(x) {return(x)}` when you know that `x` has actually been returned?

Comment: The OP didn't even show a call to the function, the output shown could be whatever even if it looks like the output of this function. Again it is the question author responsibility to FIX his/her question not yours. Now, do whatever you want, if you want to re apply your edit, go for it, I won't spend more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
outer(as.vector(tt[,1]), as.vector(d[,1]), function(x,y){x*y/(td*ee)})
```

Use vectorization to accelerate the computation.

Comment: I just don't have enough reputations to comment on the problem yet

Comment: sorry bro my bad!

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my answer which gives a direct answer.